# Add a new Postgresql node to pgpool

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I am planning to use a pgpool instance with 2 Postgresql databases only to run parallel query without replication.
Can I add a new node to pgpool without blocking the whole system?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can add another postgresql server. Prepare your database and the open your pgpool.conf file and add another server on it and reload your pgpool.

Reload command is: service pgpool reload

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure OP wanted the steps to add a new node for a running pgpool2 instance.

In short:

- prepare the new node
- add it to pgpool.conf
- reload pgpool configuration
- attach the new node (`pcp_attach_node`)
- sync the new instance with the others (`pcp_recovery_node`)

Don't forget to check results at the end of sync.

The whole procedure is in pgpool2 documentation: https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-online-recovery.html